# CSS - style similar to GOOD?

Tags: css, layout, background, z-index

I frequent a website called [GOOD](http://www.good.is/) and I love one aesthetic style in particular; how the navigation bar extends its colours across the background of the website. You'll see what I mean if you visit the site.

In CSS, how could I replicate this in the most simply way possible? I've tried all sorts of things with z-index/margins/float and it simply isn't happening.

Comment: Why don't you take the HTML and CSS from that site, and chop out all the irrelevant stuff?  What you're left with will be the code you need.

Comment: Yes, or use a tool like Chrome's DOM inspector or CSSEdit or the like to find the relevant parts of the page markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put A div (position'd absolute) in the back with the menu in it and put another div, with the actual content in it over that.

Little example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="position: absolute; top:200px; left:0px; width:100%">The menu here, at A 100% width</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top:0px; left: 0px;">The content here.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That should work!

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is that now it won't be "behind" everything else, and the z-index is not working for me.

Comment: But the Z-index is only working when you have A absolute or relative or fixed positioned div. With the above example it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Its all about position: absolute. The nav container which holds all of those links is given this CSS property which removes it from the normal flow of the page. It has top: 165px to set it where it is positioned. Each of the links are given the display: block property which means they will fill their parent which in this case is 100% of the width. A span tag is then used inside the 100% width links to set the text where it is.